# Why is -1**2 a syntax error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exponentiation, ecmascript-2016

Executing it in the browser console it says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token **`.
Trying it in node:

```
> -1**2
...
...
...
...^C
```

I thought this is an arithmetic expression where `**` is the power operator. There is no such issue with other operators.

Strangely, typing `*/` on the second line triggers the execution:

```
> -1**2
... */
-1**2
  ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token **
```

What is happening here?

Comment: It is supposed to be supported in ECMA2016. http://2ality.com/2016/02/exponentiation-operator.html

Comment: Try this instead: `(-1)**2`.

Comment: firefox says: `SyntaxError: unparenthesized unary expression can't appear on the left-hand side of '**'` - you must be using Chrome - the error message is totally useless at best

Comment: same goes for `+1**2`

Comment: @JaromandaX In my Firefox 49 on OSX i got `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '*'`.

Comment: @psmith - update :p

Comment: @JaromandaX The error message was the same in Firefox 51 as well, but from Firefox 52 i also get very clear error what you posted above.

Comment: @psmith, that is because FireFox implemented the `**` operator [in version 52](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_Next_support_in_Mozilla). The syntax error you got in older versions reflects that `**` was not supported at all (nothing related to precedence or parentheses).

Comment: @JaromandaX Why vendetta with chrome ?

Comment: JS never ceases to amaze me. `'1'+2` is `'12'` and `'1'-2` is `-1` but `-1**2` raises an error because it could be ambiguous? Wow.

Comment: Any idea about the second part of my question? Why Node asks for more input (i.e. showing the `...`) after typing `-1**2`?

Comment: @A---B - it's an *opinion* - why is it important enough for you to ask?

Comment: @JaromandaX Would you rather people be using IE? xD

Comment: @EricDuminil All the old WTFs are exactly why they're trying to be very careful with new features!

Comment: @JaromandaX, yea, but it could be worse, it could be [any other browser other than chrome](https://cvedetails.com)

Comment: @gman According to their [top 50 flawed products](https://www.cvedetails.com/top-50-products.php?year=0), IE has had fewer known flaws than Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Ie had had 11 versions . Vs 50+. So divide the number of flaws by the number of versions ...

Comment: @curiousdannii: So now we're stuck with old, lazy WTFs and new, overzealous WTFs. The best of both worlds! :)

Comment: @CeesTimmerman, if you pick any particular full year you'll see chrome has less than 1/10th as many code execution bugs as any other browser. Let's pick 2016. FF has 26x more code execution bugs, Safari has 15x, Edge has 37x,

Comment: @gman Do you mean JavaScript code execution bugs? That'd be because it has a different JavaScript engine, and as we know from PHP "works" =/= "works correctly". If you mean native code execution bugs it's because Edge combines the worse parts of IE with the instability of the Metro UI, Safari runs an old version of Apple WebKit (whereas Chrome uses a more beta version) and Firefox is used by the sort of people who play with everything (i.e. developers) more than most other browsers.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Look again. IE has two separate entries. "IE" and "Internet Explorer." The sum of the two (1481 total) actually brings it up to *number 3* in that list, just topping both Chrome and Firefox. I'm also of the opinion that the reason those applications are so high is simply because they're used so much and are so important; this means that people are more likely to look for and find vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> Executing it in the browser console says SyntaxError: Unexpected token **.

Because that's the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-exp-operator). Designed that way to avoid confusion about whether it's the square of the negation of one (i.e. `(-1) ** 2`), or the negation of the square of one (i.e. `-(1 ** 2)`). This design was the result of [extensive discussion](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/exponentiation-operator-precedence) of operator precedence, and examination of how this is handled in other languages, and finally the decision was made to avoid unexpected behavior by making this a syntax error.

Comment: Interesting decision from operator precedence perspective, since power always comes before addition/subtraction. Thus `-1**2` is `-1`, not `1`.

Comment: Thanks, i had this thought that the error is to avoid confusion about the operator precedence, but dropped the idea because the error message is just so misleading.

Comment: @Adriaan: Not true. In regular mathematics the negativity of numbers is not usually treated as subtraction. In fact minus one square is treated as the square of minus one not the minus of one square so it is 1 not -1. In other words, `-1` does not mean `0-1` but `1 * -1`

Comment: @slebetman `-1^2` is never treated as `(-1)^2` in mathematics. Have you ever seen how polynomials are written? We'd have to write `-(x^2)+bx+c` instead of the normally used `-x^2+bx+c` if we follow your claim. And, more generally, `a(x^2)+bx+c` instead of `ax^2+bx+c`.

Comment: And here we have yet another reminder that the way mathematicians do maths and how processors do maths are often different. One cannot make assumptions without knowing how a language functions

Comment: @slebetman "but `1 * -1`" In that case, exponentiation still takes precedence.

Comment: This comment thread seems to exactly underline why it was removed: to prevent confusion. My immediate reaction was to interpret it as `(-1)**2` because unary generally takes precedence over binary, but of course it also makes sense to have it be interpreted as `-(1**2)` for consistency with mathematics. Dropping the feature means that instead of writing something and having it work a different way, you'll just get a syntax error and look up the reasoning (on StackOverflow, perhaps!) instead, then make precedence explicit--no more confusion.

Comment: @Ruslan arguably, we should just always be writing `0 - x² + b·x + c` or else something more like `⌋x²⌊ + b·x + c`, instead of employing the `-` symbol in two hard-to-reconcile ways.

Comment: @leftaroundabout or, if we really decide to switch to more explicit notation, why not just use Reverse Polish notation? Then all ambiguity will vanish naturally.

Comment: @Ruslan: I hope you were being sarcastic. If not – _I_ would say the standard maths convention of using infix operators is pretty good and expresses the tree nature of algebraic expressions better than polish notation (reverse- or Lisp S-expressions). _Because_ it is so good, it would make sense to stop the jeopardization of its consistency which the addition of an extra rule that only applies to the (admittedly very important) special case of `-` brings about.

Comment: @Schism: Your point would make sense with any language but Javascript. JS never cared about consistency, surprising results or weird implicit conversions. In JS, I'd expect `-1**2` to return `NaN`, `[]` or `''`, but surely not raise an exception.

Comment: Incredible decision to make it a syntax error. It is *much* harder to detect as a syntax error and give this very specific error message than it is to actually implement it either way.

Comment: @EJP: That's not a very specific error message at all; it's a generic syntax error message like you'd get for almost any other syntax error. It's also not particularly hard to write the grammar to exclude expressions of the form `-thing**thing`. They just made the LHS an UpdateExpression instead of a UnaryExpression.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Javascript used to be like that, but people are doing their best not to make new design decisions in the spirit of the old.

Comment: So why is `-1 ** 2` not allowed but `-100 / -100 * 10` is?

Comment: Sorry, your documentation link doesn't say anything about parentheses in exponentiation operands. I'm going with trincot's answer.

Answer (score 41):

From the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)):

> In JavaScript, it is impossible to write an ambiguous exponentiation expression, i.e. you cannot put a unary operator (`+`/`-`/`~`/`!`/`delete`/`void`/`typeof`) immediately before the base number.

The reason is also explained in that same text:

> In most languages like PHP and Python and others that have an exponentiation operator (typically `^` or `**`), the exponentiation operator is defined to have a higher precedence than unary operators such as unary `+` and unary `-`, but there are a few exceptions. For example, in Bash the `**` operator is defined to have a lower precedence than unary operators.

So to avoid confusion it was decided that the code must remove the ambiguity and explicitly put the parentheses:

```
(-1)**2
```

or:

```
-(1**2)
```

As a side note, the *binary* `-` is not treated that way -- having lower precedence -- and so the last expression has the same result as this valid expression:

```
0-1**2
```

#### Exponentiation Precedence in Other Programming Languages

As already affirmed in above quote, most programming languages that have an infix exponentiation operator, give a higher precedence to that operator than to the unary minus.

Here are some other examples of programming languages that give a higher precedence to the unary minus operator:

- [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC13)
- [VBScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6s7zy3d1(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_operators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH5g-SW3)
- [COBOL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/tasks/tpari35.htm)
- [Rexx](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9UMF_12.1.0/ref/ref/tpc/dsq_rexx_operator.html)
- [Orc](https://orc.csres.utexas.edu/documentation/html/refmanual/ref.syntax.precedence.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link to a human readable documentation. torazaburo's link to the spec is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: When language designers cite bash as a precedent, something stupid is about to happen.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley "designers" is a very strong word when talking about people responsible for JS. If you've never tried it before, look at the results for `[]+[]`, `[]+{}`, `{}+[]` and `{}+{}`.

Comment: @EricDuminil I just tried this. My flabber has never been so completely gasted before.

Comment: @cyberbit: Credits go to [Gary Bernhardt](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).